# .htaccess redirect every other browser language to a default language

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've got a website with multiple domain redirects, and several browser language redirects.

But now I also want to redirect every other (unknown) browser language to a default language.

For example, Spanish (es) browser language gets redirected to /nl.
Whereas it should get redirected to /en, like every other unknown language should.
See my last .htaccess rule, which is not working.

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# DOMAIN REDIRECTS
# ----------------
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.eu [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/nl/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.be [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/nl/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.nl [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/nl-nl/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.fr [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/fr/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.de [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/de/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/en/ [L,R=301]

# LANGUAGE REDIRECTS
# ------------------
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-language} ^nl [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/nl/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-language} ^fr [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/fr/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-language} ^de [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/de/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-language} ^en [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/en/ [L,R=301]

# NOT WORKING
# -----------
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-language} ^!(nl|fr|de|en) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/en/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try following

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-language} !^(nl|fr|de|en).* [NC]
```

Also the last RewriteRule might cause a redirect loop so you might want to include another `RewriteCond` to check if host isn't already the host you're redirecting to.

Comment: Could you maybe explain why the `.*` and the `?` after `[NC]`?
They don't seem necessary?

**Edit:** The `.*` causes an htaccess error, when the browser language is `es-es` for example.

Comment: My bad about `?`, it just got copied over from my comment. Regarding `.*`, since the accept-language string is longer than only two letters of language code (that you're aware of), I like to be verbose. Not sure why it is generating error though. Please write a comment or better edit my answer if you figure out why.